# Triggering CSS transition for a height change by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I am trying to trigger a transition effect for an element by changing height with javascript. I've searched for an answer, but all I could find was using the css animation instead and my code is not compatible with that idea. Here is my code ;

```js
function printVolumeLevel(level) {
  var volumeDiv = document.getElementById('volume_level');
  volumeDiv.innerHTML = "";
  var iconVolume = document.getElementById('icon_volume');
  iconVolume.innerHTML = "";

  if (OutputSettings.isAudioMuted() === false) {
    iconVolume.innerHTML += "<div  class=\"volumeOn\" /> \n";

    volumeDiv.innerHTML += "<div  class=\"volumeLevelUnfocus\" /> \n";
    volumeDiv.innerHTML += "<div  class=\"volumeLevelFocus\" /> \n";

    var volumeHeight = level * 40;

    document.getElementsByClassName("volumeLevelFocus")[0].style.height = volumeHeight + "px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("volumeLevelUnfocus")[0].style.height = (800 - volumeHeight) + "px";

  } else {
    iconVolume.innerHTML += "<div  class=\"volumeOff\" /> \n";
    document.getElementsByClassName("volumeLevelUnfocus")[0].style.setProperty("height", "800px");
  }
}
```

```css
.volumeLevelFocus {
  background: #da1c5c;
  width: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  height: 400px;
}

.volumeLevelUnfocus {
  background: #111a21;
  width: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.2s;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="volume_level"></div>
```

Comment: it's look like you are not closing your div injected in your DOM :/

Comment: Tried closing them,transition still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code:

1. You can not close divs by `/>`, it muse be closed by `</div>`.
2. To line break in html you must use `<br>` not "\n" .
3. You did not add the div `id="icon_volume"`.
4. If you want to add an element and change its style by transition, the change must be done with another process(In the answer setTimeot);

Your code is some thing like this:

> Insert_a_div_with_height(0px);
>
> Make_the_height_of_Inserted_div(800px);

**It only adds a div with 800px height**, so there is no style change and therefore no transition.

Below is a simlified answer:

```css
    .volumeLevelUnfocus {
         background: #111a21;
         width: 40px;
       
        transition-duration: 5s;
        height:400px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="volume_level"></div>
    

    <script>
        var volumeDiv = document.getElementById('volume_level');
        volumeDiv.innerHTML = ""; 
       
        volumeDiv.innerHTML += "<div  class=\"volumeLevelUnfocus\" style='height:0px;'></div>";
          
       //another process to change the height of inserted div:
       setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName("volumeLevelUnfocus")[0].style.height = "800px";
       }, 100);

    </script>
```

Comment: And, so the OP, and future visitors, might learn, those problems are..? Please [edit] your answer to explain your answer.

Comment: It only helps this user, I saw many posts like this. And if it is useless it will be closed so my answer do not disturb any one. :)

Comment: I couldnt see the difference,actually

Comment: Yeah they are good advices,but they dont solve my actual problem

Comment: @UğurKURT, Is it now answers you or not? If there is still problems let me know.